# issue with the Owl carousel because of an incorrect linking of something?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I am attempting to incorporate the Owl Carousel into my latest project, but I seem to be encountering some difficulties with it. At this point, only the HTML and CSS seem to be functioning correctly. I believe I may be making a mistake with the Script, but I am unsure of what exactly I am doing wrong. Can someone kindly assist me and examine my code to identify where I am going wrong?

My css

```css
     #work_process {
       background-color: #f9f9f9;
       padding: 50px 0;
     }
     
     #work_process h5 {
       font-size: 18px;
       color: #555;
     }
     
     #work_process h3 {
       font-size: 36px;
       font-weight: bold;
       margin-top: 20px;
       margin-bottom: 50px;
     }
     
     .work_box {
       background-color: #fff;
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       border-radius: 5px;
       padding: 20px;
       text-align: center;
     }
     
     .work_box h6 {
       font-size: 18px;
       margin-top: 30px;
       margin-bottom: 20px;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: #333;
     }
     
     .work_box p {
       font-size: 14px;
       color: #555;
       line-height: 1.5;
       margin-bottom: 30px;
     }
     
     .step_box {
       width: 70px;
       height: 70px;
       border-radius: 50%;
       background-color: #555;
       color: #fff;
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
       margin: 0 auto;
       margin-bottom: 30px;
     }
     
     .step_box h4 {
       font-size: 24px;
       font-weight: bold;
       margin: 0;
     }
     
     .owl-carousel .owl-nav button {
       color: #555;
       font-size: 24px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       transform: translateY(-50%);
       z-index: 1;
       background-color: transparent;
       border: none;
       outline: none;
       cursor: pointer;
     }
     
     .owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev {
       left: 0;
     }
     
     .owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next {
       right: 0;
     }
     
     .owl-carousel .owl-dots {
       text-align: center;
       margin-top: 50px;
     }
     
     .owl-carousel .owl-dots button {
       width: 10px;
       height: 10px;
       border-radius: 50%;
       background-color: #ccc;
       margin: 0 5px;
       border: none;
       outline: none;
       cursor: pointer;
       transition: all 0.3s;
     }
     
     .owl-carousel .owl-dots button.active {
       background-color: #555;
     }
     //css
    #work_process {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      padding: 50px 0;
    }
    
    #work_process h5 {
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #555;
    }
    
    #work_process h3 {
      font-size: 36px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    
    .work_box {
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .work_box h6 {
      font-size: 18px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #333;
    }
    
    .work_box p {
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #555;
      line-height: 1.5;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .step_box {
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #555;
      color: #fff;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .step_box h4 {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .owl-carousel .owl-nav button {
      color: #555;
      font-size: 24px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      z-index: 1;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev {
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next {
      right: 0;
    }
    
    .owl-carousel .owl-dots {
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .owl-carousel .owl-dots button {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #ccc;
      margin: 0 5px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    
    .owl-carousel .owl-dots button.active {
      background-color: #555;
    }
```

Here is html

```html
<div id="work_process" class="py-5">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h5>Working Process</h5>
    <h3 class="mt-3">See how we work</h3>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-loaded owl-drag">

      <div class="owl-stage-outer">
        <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-2825px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 4520px;">
          <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 5</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-palmtree"></span>
              <h6 class="">Bag up all your dirty clothes</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 6</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-chart-line"></span>
              <h6 class="">We Pick Your Cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 7</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-admin-generic"></span>
              <h6 class="">We Clean &amp; dry Your Cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 8</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-admin-tools"></span>
              <h6 class="">We deliver your clean cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 1</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-palmtree"></span>
              <h6 class="">Bag up all your dirty clothes</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 2</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-chart-line"></span>
              <h6 class="">We Pick Your Cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 3</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-admin-generic"></span>
              <h6 class="">We Clean &amp; dry Your Cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 4</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-admin-tools"></span>
              <h6 class="">We deliver your clean cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 5</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-palmtree"></span>
              <h6 class="">Bag up all your dirty clothes</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 6</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-chart-line"></span>
              <h6 class="">We Pick Your Cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 7</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-admin-generic"></span>
              <h6 class="">We Clean &amp; dry Your Cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 8</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-admin-tools"></span>
              <h6 class="">We deliver your clean cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item cloned active" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 1</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-palmtree"></span>
              <h6 class="">Bag up all your dirty clothes</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item cloned active" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 2</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-chart-line"></span>
              <h6 class="">We Pick Your Cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 3</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-admin-generic"></span>
              <h6 class="">We Clean &amp; dry Your Cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 262.5px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="work_box text-center p-3 my-5">
              <div class="step_box">
                <h4>Step 4</h4>
              </div>
              <span class="icon1 mt-5 dashicons dashicons-admin-tools"></span>
              <h6 class="">We deliver your clean cloths</h6>
              <p>Consectetur adipiscing elisesd do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-nav disabled"><button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-prev"><span aria-label="Previous">‹</span></button><button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-next"><span aria-label="Next">›</span></button></div>
      <div class="owl-dots"><button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button><button role="button" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any problem here <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
 
      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
 
       });
</script>

Comment: Please add your javascript to the question as well